# What is the alternative of getHeader() method of patternlayout in log4j 1.x in log4j 2

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

```
final PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout() {
        @Override
        public String getHeader() {
            // return super.getHeader();
            // Get all column names & print them
            String columnName = "";
            if (fieldsToLog != null) {
                for (int index = 0; index < fieldsToLog.length; index++) {
                    columnName = (index == 0) ? (columnName + fieldsToLog[index].getDisplayName()) : (columnName
                            + ";" + fieldsToLog[index].getDisplayName());
                }
                columnName += ";\n";
            }
            return columnName;
        }
    };
    layout.getHeader();
    // layout.setConversionPattern("[%t]%m%n");
    layout.setConversionPattern("%m%n");
```

Where can I wirte the getheader() code in log4j 2.As I need to ultimately create logger

Comment: log4j v2 `public byte[] getHeader()` returns array of bytes. You might be able to do some work with `AbstractStringLayout.getHeaderSerializer`. But what do you really want to do with header?

Comment: Why would need the header to create a Logger? One has nothing to do with the other.